# How can I move this viewcontroller-reliant method over to a helper class?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, design-patterns, uiviewcontroller, abstraction

I am using the Evernote API, and I have created a helper class that will contain the Evernote API-specific methods in an effort to keep code as abstracted as possible.

But there is one method that needs to be called from the view controller to show a login form, as well as an alertView if an error occurs. Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)loginToEvernote:(id)sender {

EvernoteSession *session = [EvernoteSession sharedSession];
[session authenticateWithViewController:self completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error || !session.isAuthenticated) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"Could not authenticate"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    } else {

    }
}];
```

}

It seems to me the "authenticateWithViewController:completionHandler" method needs to be in a view controller, in order to show the modal view controller that contains the login information.

Again, this is a method from an API, so I cannot alter it.

How can I move this method over to the helper class? At first I thought delegation, but I am already making **this view controller the delegate of the helper class** in order to send other error messages to it, and making the helper class and viewcontroller delegates of each other seems code-smelly to me, if it's even possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Evernote API requires a view controller, and you want complete abstraction, I would have a method in the helper class like this something like this in the helper class:

```
- (void)authenticateWithViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

In this method, you can encapsulate any shared behaviours, calling through to the Evernote session API passing the `viewController` parameter to the method.